# birational equivalence for log Calabi-Yau varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

What I call a log Calabi-Yau variety is a smooth quasi-projective variety $U$ that admits a smooth compactification $X$ by a normal crossing divisor $D$ such that $-D$ is anticanonical. Or probably it's better to consider the log Calabi-Yau pair $(X, D)$. Is there a well-established of notion of birational equivalence of two such pairs?